# JavaFX Chart animation finished

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I need to grab the chart plot background for its bounds, but I can't do that until the chart is laid out.

If I set the chart data, then try to get those bounds, it will return values of `0`.

As a workaround, I delay those calculations with the help of a thread. For now it'll do, but the UI is kinda flickering due to my manual delay in the thread.

Does the JavaFX Node(s) have `onAnimationFinished` APIs or something like that?

Comment: There's no such API. I'd recommend turning the animation off if you need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this sort of problem was to create the charting elements in a new window, and then to do all of the actual calculations and laying out of the elements BEFORE I show the window, then I attach a 'WINDOW_SHOWN' listener to it, and run whatever analysis I need after that. For example:

```
 wellDiagram.setLabel(current_position_label);
        wellDiagram.setScaleLabels(zero_scale_labels_bottom, full_scale_labels_bottom);
        wellDiagram.setProperties();
        GraphWindow.get_stage().addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                    //DO some stuff to get the bounds of your chart, etc. etc. 
                    //I use it to automatically save an image of the graph with one
                    //One kind of css, and then switch it back to a nice looking one. 
                }
            }
        });
        wellDiagram.setError(lbl_error_label, GraphWindow.graphWindowReturner().getErrorMessage());
```

If you can't do it with a new window... I'm not totally sure.